# Modeling response times

Tags: poisson-distribution

I am trying to model the time lapse between when a user sees an ad and when they call the advertiser (presuming they do).  I have two issues - part of the data seems exponential, but I am wondering if there is a similar distribution with an extra parameter because I cannot quite get it to fit.  Also, the peak does not occur at t = 0 but rather at t = 30s or so - obviously people do not call immediately, as there is a necessary physical delay between seeing the ad and picking up the phone.  But some people do call at 2 seconds, or 3, etc, and as I mentioned, the peak is at 30.  Is there a simple way to model this?

Answer (score 4):

The Weibull distribution [1]  is a generalization of the exponential distribution that is often used in time-to-event analysis. Also note that you can use non-parametric methods like Kaplan-Meier estimates that fit the distribution you actually have, instead of trying to fit into an arbitrary category.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

Answer (score 3):

not an expert, but maybe the ex-gaussian (gaussian plus exponential distribution)?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_minus_exponential_distribution

http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/gamlss.dist/html/exGAUS.html

http://www.tqmp.org/doc/vol4-1/p35-45_Lacouture.pdf

From the last link:

> In the framework of cognitive
>   processes, this convolution can be
>   seen as representing the overall
>   distribution of RT [Response Time] resulting from two
>   additive or sequential processes. As
>   proposed by Luce (1986, chap. 6), the
>   exponential process can be seen as the
>   decision component, i.e., the time
>   required to decide which response to
>   make, while the Gaussian component can
>   be conceptualized as the transduction
>   component, i.e., the sum of the time
>   required by the sensory process and
>   the time required to physically make
>   the response.